# Saving incoming webRTC stream to blob in node environment

Tags: node.js, webrtc, janus-gateway, mediarecorder-api

I am trying to make use of the MediaStream object (from node-webrtc, which works like browser API).

The problem is, that there is no MediaRecorder available in the Node environment.

I use Janode to connect to the Janus WebRTC server and get the live stream. I then set up WebRTC and have it ready to stream and track objects. 
How can I save them to file as with MediaRecorder? I prefer blob first, but it can be straight to file.

```
import express from "express";
import { createServer as create HTTP server } from "HTTP";
import Janode from "janode";
import StreamingPlugin from "janode/plugins/streaming";
import wrtc from "wrtc";

const { RTCPeerConnection, RTCSessionDescription, MediaStream } = wrtc;

const app = express();

const connection = await Janode.connect({
  is_admin: false,
  address: {
    url: "janusServerUrl",
    apisecret: "secret",
  },
});
const session = await connection.create();

const streamingHandle = await session.attach(StreamingPlugin);

const peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection();

peerConnection.ontrack = (event) => {
  if (event.track.kind != "video") return;
  const stream = new MediaStream();
  stream.addTrack(event.track)
}

const { jsep, restart = false } = await streamingHandle.watch({ id: 1 });
await peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(jsep));
const answer = await peerConnection.createAnswer();
await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
```

I have tried Puppeteer, and it works, but I still want to do it in a Node environment to reduce workload.